# VB .NET dynamically call control.Validating event using reflection

Tags: vb.net, events, reflection

For each Control c in a Form I need to dynamically discover its Validating event and call it.

I can get the event info:

```
 Dim ei As EventInfo = c.GetType.GetEvent("Validating")
```

I can get the list of events:

```
Dim events As System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList =
            CType(c.GetType.InvokeMember("Events", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic, Nothing, c, Nothing), EventHandlerList)
```

I tried to:

```
Dim fi As FieldInfo = c.GetType.GetField("EventValidating", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```

But fi is always Nothing.

I can't put these together and find the event handler and then call it.

Comment: Did you try iterating through the list of events to find if any of them match what you're looking for?

Comment: yes, the Validating event is there, but I can't call it.